# General questions re: Wordpress and WP plugins

Tags: plugins

I don't have any coding skills, and I would really appreciate if somebody could help me out and tell me if it's possible to make a website with WP given my 0 experience with websites creation.

My website idea is kind of a mix of yelp and freelancer.com with some additional features.
I would like it to have two main groups of users (apart from Admin):
Personal
Business

Each of these groups would have its own set of rights. 
But Business would also have several subtypes within it, like Restaurants, Beauty salons, etc. 
Any business could create its own profile on the website, if this particular business does not yet have a profile on the website (Admin or "personal" users could create a business profile, too, and then a business owner could "claim" that it's theirs).
All the businesses could be viewed by the website visitors either on a map, or as a list.
Any business' profile page could be commented and rated by "Personal" users; and business owners could answer those comments.

"Personal" users could buy some kind of a "Pro" subscription with a monthly fee; then these users could offer their services on the website. Other personal users could either contact these "Pro" users directly, or they could post a task, and "Pro" users would submit their offers to the task.

I would also like to have events calendar on the website; any user could post an event, but only after it is approved by the Admin.

I read a lot about WP plugins and I found some that looked like they could help me build the features I need.

But I'm not sure if all WP plugins are kind of "compatible" with each other. Would I still need some coding skills to edit something in the code here and there?

I would really appreciate some advice, as I am not sure that I will be able to develop what I need, and so maybe paying for the "Business" WP tariff will not help me build the website ^^^ on my own with no coding skills at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, Blair.  Your question is a little off-topic for this site.  You may need to distill this down to a specific problem (such as "I can't get 'A' to work with 'B' and here is what I've tried so far").  That being said, in general, plugins may or may not be compatible - it depends on whether the author followed WP standards or not. But, you should not be editing core plugin files (although that doesn't mean you can't customize a plugin).  Each of these is a fairly broad topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking if you can build a website without any experience.  The answer is yes, maybe.   Could you build an airplane without experience?  Yes, maybe.  Why though? would it be safe and work correctly?  Who knows?

Spend time on things you're good at and hire someone who is good at developing websites.  You'll spend less time overall and certainly less time being frustrated.  Your website is your online presence.  I wouldn't pinch pennies or "hope for the best". Get it done properly.

**If you're going to build a website, and build it right, it will require coding.**

I'm assuming here you're not trying to start a career in web development.  If you are planning on going that route, start small, don't go with a production-level site that's going to upset customers if it doesn't work.